# Laravel 5.4 field doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am having this error and none of the googled result i checked is similar to my problem.

I have an application with class Deal, User, and Matches

A deal has many matches.
A user has many matches.
A user has many deals.

I am attempting to create a new Match using my Deal object

```
$deal->matches()->create(['user_id'=>$id]);
```

This is my match class, i have defined all needed relationships

```
class Match extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $expired_on = "";


    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->matched_on = $model->freshTimestamp();
        });
    }

    public function __construct(){
        $d = (new \DateTime($this->matched_on))->modify('+1 day');
        $this->expired_on = $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }


    /**
     * Get the user that owns the match.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    /**
     * Get the deal that owns the match.
     */
    public function deal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Deal');
    }
}
```

And i keep getting this error when i attempt to create a new match.

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `matches` (`deal_id`) values (1))

I have my guarded to be an empty array, what could be the problem?

Comment: What I don't get is why matches has a model class if it's a pivot table https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: This is usually generated when you don't insert a certain field that cannot be NULL or doesn't have a default value. So your 'user_id' does not get inserted

Comment: @Cr1xus, yes my 'user_id' does not get inserted, my issue now is why is it so, seeing that i have it in my create method.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Remove the `guarded` array and add the `fillable` instead:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'deal_id'];
```

Comment: Will do that, but nothing is wrong with using _guarded_ according to the documentation

Comment: 'guarded' does the opposite (like $guarded = ['id']; means do not allow to update the id), so, you should either use 'fillable' or 'guarded'.

Answer (score 39):

If you would like to revert to previous behavior, update your

> config/database.php

file and set `'strict' => false` for your connection.

Comment: Do you need to run any artisan clear commands, or refresh migrate after this?

Comment: Use  new comand in Laravel 5.5  php artisan migrate:fresh --seed and have fun :)

Comment: Thanks.  So, your saying it does need a rerun of the migration then? For the record i think that is `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`.  Unless there is a fresh I don't know about.  ;-)

Comment: yes I did that and it worked, migrate:fresh is new command look that https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-5

Answer (score 9):

Since it was a unique field in my case, I could not make it nullable.

For me, I had an empty constructor which was causing the issue don't know why.
Please comment if anyone knows the reason.

```
public function __construct(){

}
```

Commenting/removing it resolved the issue.

Comment: Can confirm this is a thing.  I just ran into it as well.  I removed the empty constructor class and the "field doesn't have a default value" error disappeared.

Comment: @vivek-takrani See [davee44's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59866152/2530736) for the reason. Apparently the fields get passed to the parent through the constructor. Calling the parent constructor with arguments solved the problem for me.

Comment: Confirmed. Need to call parent constructor
! and pass attributes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59866152/3163536

Comment: Confirmed. Empty constructor in class was the problem.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a constructor in your model, just make sure it has a call to a parent constructor as well:

```
public function __construct( array $attributes = array() ) {
    // mandatory
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    //..
}
```

Otherwise, it will break some functionality like `Model::create`.

Comment: This fixed my problem

Comment: I spent forever on this issue and nothing helped until I tried this.

Answer (score 7):

I am using Laravel 8 and fixed this error thorugh this two steps:

1. move the word from `$guarded` array to `$fillable` array in User Mode
2. Config.database.php:  `'strict' => false` in the array of `'mysql'`

Answer (score 5):

**Alexey Mezenin's** Answer is correct and a good one.

Another way i used around it, for those who want to maintain the guarded empty array is to create a new Match object and put in the attributes and save.

```
            $match->user_id = $id;
            $match->deal_id = $deal->id;
            $match->matched_on = $match->freshTimestamp();
            $match->save();
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way around this error is to include

'strict' => false,

into config/database.php within mysql array

Answer (score 1):

When manually importing / exporting the databases, check if the transfer of all table settings was successful. If you forget to add an auto increment primary key, Laravel doesn't fill the value for you.

Adding the `AUTO_INCREMENT` afterwards will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error but my wrong was making class model:

```
$book = new Book();
```

While this is true

```
$book = new Book($request->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

changing your "config/database.php" won't help.
If you're getting this error, you're not sending the data to database correctly.
check your function in your controller, the create() method is probably being blocked by an if statement or something.
or

if it's an API, check the post request from the frontend that's where your issue is.
make sure the form is correctly passed into to request.