# Make custom ID automatic in seeder Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to make custom `id` using haruncpi/laravel-id-generator packages.
I have 2 data that will insert into database. the program is work but the id of those data is duplicate

here is code

```php
class ArtisSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function CustomId() 
    {
        $config = [
            'table' => 'artis', 
            'field' => 'kd_artis',
            'length' => 4, 
            'prefix' => 'A'
        ];

        return IdGenerator::generate($config);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('artis')->insert([
            [
                'kd_artis' => $this->CustomId(),
                'nm_artis' => 'ROBERT DOWNEY',
                'jk' => 'PRIA',
                'bayaran' => 10000000000,
                'award' => 2,
                'negara' => 'AS',
            ], 
            [
                'kd_artis' => $this->CustomId(),
                'nm_artis' => 'ANGELINA JOLIE',
                'jk' => 'WANITA',
                'bayaran' => 700000000,
                'award' => 1,
                'negara' => 'AS',
            ], 
        ]);
    }
}
```

note : kd_artis is the `id`.

So how to make the `id` not duplicate?

Comment: why don't you use default helper to generate ids? `Str::uuid()->toString()`

Comment: @Kavan Prajapati because i want my id like this 'A001 A002 A003'

Comment: You could use faker and something like `$faker->unique()->numerify('A###');`

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden is it possible to make the id sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

You can save and manage much more easily through Eloquent. Use like this in Seeder:

```
Artis::insert([
    [
        'nm_artis' => 'ROBERT DOWNEY',
        'jk' => 'PRIA',
        'bayaran' => 10000000000,
        'award' => 2,
        'negara' => 'AS',
    ],
    [
        'nm_artis' => 'ANGELINA JOLIE',
        'jk' => 'WANITA',
        'bayaran' => 700000000,
        'award' => 1,
        'negara' => 'AS',
    ],
]);
```

Don't forget to include this in your Model. You can customize it according to you:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->kd_artis = IdGenerator::generate([
            'table' => $this->table,
            'field' => 'kd_artis',
            'length' => 4,
            'prefix' => 'A',
        ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: i little bit confused about use Artis::createMany. i get error like this

'Call to undefined method App\Models\Artis::createMany()

Bad Method Call: Did you mean App\Models\Artis::created() ?'

Comment: i also add 'use App\Models\Artis;'

Comment: @MuhammadHakim try using `insert()` instead of `createMany()`.

Comment: laravel outputs this error "General error: 1364 Field 'kd_artis' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: Can u check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64570060/10542740