# Doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel

I am using below code to insert record in Database using API.

```
public function table_order_bill( $table_id, Request $request )
    {
        $table_orders = RestaurantTableOrder::where('table_id',$table_id)->where( 'restaurant_id', $request->vendor->restaurants[0]->id )->first();
        if($table_orders) {
$table_order['restaurant_id'] = $table_orders->restaurant_id;  // I have Restaurant ID here.
            $table_order['table_id'] = $table_orders->table_id;
            $table_order['order_amount'] = $table_orders->order_amount;
            $table_order['restaurant_discount_amount'] = $table_orders->restaurant_discount_amount;
            $table_order['total_tax_amount'] = $table_orders->total_tax_amount;
            $table_order['order_status'] = $table_orders->order_status;

            //return response()->json( ['restaurant_id' => $table_orders->restaurant_id ]);


            $order = new Order;
            $order->fill($table_order);
            $result = $order->save();
```

I am getting error `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'restaurant_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into` orders `(`order_status`,` updated_at`,` created_at`) values (0, 2023-09-10 11:07:49, 2023-09-10 11:07:49)) in file`.

If I use this code `return response()->json( $table_order );`, I am getting below output.

```
{
    "restaurant_id": 51,
    "table_id": 5,
    "order_amount": "2.34",
    "restaurant_discount_amount": "0.00",
    "total_tax_amount": "0.39",
    "order_status": 0
}
```

If I am using this code.

```
 public function table_order_bill( $table_id, Request $request )
    {
        $table_orders = RestaurantTableOrder::where('table_id',$table_id)->where( 'restaurant_id', $request->vendor->restaurants[0]->id )->first();
        if($table_orders) {
            $table_order['restaurant_id'] = $table_orders->restaurant_id;
            $table_order['table_id'] = $table_orders->table_id;
            $table_order['order_amount'] = $table_orders->order_amount;
            $table_order['restaurant_discount_amount'] = $table_orders->restaurant_discount_amount;
            $table_order['total_tax_amount'] = $table_orders->total_tax_amount;
            $table_order['order_status'] = $table_orders->order_status;
            return response()->json( ['restaurant_id' => $table_orders->restaurant_id ]);
```

I am getting this result.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.4 field doesn't have a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186521/laravel-5-4-field-doesnt-have-a-default-value)

Comment: you assign `$table_orders` and then use `$table_order`. Is that just in the question or is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 'restaurant_id' in your fillable property array of Order model ?

```
protected $fillable = ['restaurant_id', ...];
```

Or manually mass assign

```
$order = new Order();
$order->restaurant_id = $table_orders->restaurant_id;
...
$order->save();
```